# How do I use a select query to get the least of one value for each unique second value?

Tags: sql, select, min

There are groups like this;

```
USER_ID SEQ_ID NAME
1       2      Armut
1       3      Elma
1       4      Kiraz
2       1      Nar
2       2      Uzum
4       3      Sheftali
4       4      Karpuz
4       5      Kavun
```

After select query I want to see only;

```
USER_ID SEQ_ID NAME
1       2      Armut
2       1      Nar
4       3      Karpuz
```

That is, I want the row with the least SEQ_ID for each USER_ID. What SQL query will give me this result?

Best regards

Comment: What's that? A random SEQ_ID für each distinct USER_ID?

Comment: Please describe a bit more. What is the pattern here. It's the fist of user one and two but the second of user four.

Comment: (1) Homework? (2) Can you at least textually (if not using SQL) describe how the result table was created?

Comment: Ah, I get it. Smallest `SEQ_ID` for every `USER_ID`.

Comment: Stephan: No, that doesn't work for the group with USER_ID 4. The smallest SEQ_ID would be 3 there.

Comment: @Stephan202: Wrong (4,3,Sheftali)

Comment: Sorry, my divination ball said nothing about that...

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: If there were a `5  3  Helva` in the desired output, I would say it's because the initials spell "ANKH", but there isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like it should be:

```
SELECT USER_ID, MIN(SEQ_ID) AS SEQ_ID, NAME
FROM table
GROUP BY USER_ID, NAME
ORDER BY USER_ID;
```

Comment: That doesn't work for the group with USER_ID 4. The smallest SEQ_ID would be 3 there.

Comment: @Greg: powertip--indent text with four spaces to have it formatted as code. Clicking the orange question mark you see in the toolbar when posting takes you to a doc describing this and other formatting.

Comment: thanks Greg for the help.
It was my mistake, that must be 3 instead of 4.
Thanks for your understanding my question.
best regards

ps:it would be better asking "if you mean 3" instead of judging me with minus vote...

Comment: blgnklc: It wasn't obvious from your question what exactly you wanted. Basically there is an arbitrary number of possible options. And there it an arbitrary number of possible options if you include minor mistakes or typos. And a downvote means "This question is unclear or not useful" which, for a clearly unclear question, seems very much to be the case.

Comment: @blgnklc: when you get downvoted for an unclear question, you can edit the question and clarify. You'll then get upvoted. That's just how SO works.

Comment: @outis: I have cleared the question so why I am still minus 2? </br> never mind.. </br> best regards –

Comment: @blgnklc: "this result" is still ambiguous. My answer, for instance, is still a valid answer for your question, though it shouldn't be. State that you want the row with the least SEQ_ID for every USER_ID, if that's a fair description.

Comment: @outis: I want the row with the least SEQ_ID for every USER_ID.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT USER_ID, SEQ_ID, NAME 
  FROM table
  WHERE NAME IN ('Armut', 'Nar', 'Karpuz')
  ORDER BY USER_ID
```

If you have something else in mind, please clarify your question.

Comment: Except I had it wrong at first. Forgot the `ORDER BY` clause.